# Specify which version of installed dependency to use with `install.packages`

Tags: r, dependencies, install.packages

Trying to install a package on HPC (where I cannot remove root packages) I get:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotly’ in
>   loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): 
>   namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required

But I already have installed the latest version in my home and made it the first in the library search paths:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/ajabadi/R_libs"
[2] "/usr/local/easybuild/software/R/3.5.0-GCC-6.2.0/lib64/R/library"

packageVersion("rlang", lib.loc=.libPaths()[1])
[1] ‘0.4.4.9000’

packageVersion("rlang", lib.loc=.libPaths()[2])
[1] ‘0.3.1’
```

I was wondering how I can tell `install.packages` to first look at `.libPaths()[1]`. I tried `R_LIBS_USER = "~/R_libs"` in `~/.Renviron` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For packages available on github (or gitlab accordingly) you can always do:

```
devtools::install_github("user/repo", dependencies = FALSE)
```

And then load the more recent version of the dependency.